# The meaning of ぐっぽぐっぽ ; グッポグッポ ; グポグポ(?) ; ぐぽぐぽ(?)

Tags: translation, meaning, onomatopoeia

I came across this ぐっぽぐっぽ word while reading doujinshi.
"**ぐっぽぐっぽ**セッXス穴ほじくってる"

From the images shown when I searched for its meaning, it seems to be the sound made when sucking something.
Does it have more specific meaning(s) or usage(s)?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

グポグポ is similar to ズポズポ (see your previous question), but feels more dirty, vulgar or "sticky" to me. It's perhaps used mainly in sexual contexts, but you may see グポッ also to describe a "gore" sound made when someone stuck his arm into someone's abdomen.

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete explanation, as always, naruto-san.